# How to cycle between literals at the cursors point?

Tags: text-editing

Are there packages that can quickly toggle/cycle values under the cursor?

For example:

- `t` <-> `nil`
- `<=` <-> `>=`
- `+` <-> `-`
- `when` <-> `unless`

... using a list of preset values for example.

I started writing something that does this but wondered if there was something else out there already.

---

There do seem to be some packages that handle this, although I'm not so happy with them:

- [rotate-text](https://github.com/nschum/rotate-text.el) - basically what I'm looking for but doesn't support operators from what I could tell (perhaps possible with custom regex).
- [Do Re Mi](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) - overly complex/abstract, seems like it could be used for cycling anything but I would end up writing my own back-end which is basically the same as writing my own package.

... also, neither of these (as far as I can tell)  deal with undo, so every cycle steps adds an undo step.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you (but Icicles offers some commands that are relevant, such as `icicle-toggle-option` if the cursor's on an option name). But if the question under your question is about toggling option values, then a simple way to do it is to use the Customize interface - keep the Customize buffer for the option open, and use it to quickly toggle the value.

Comment: You could write yourself a command that uses a list of toggle values. It would be simple enough to get the value at point, look it up in your list, and replace it in the buffer with its opposite.

Comment: Yep, I might do my own package for this then, but it might not be _that_ simple: the devil is in the details, how to extract `&&` from `foo[0]&&(bar(1))`, `thing-at-point` doesn't seem to have an option to deal with operators, I'll check on my own solution if emacs doesn't have something built-in.